# Pass fetch success response to child component

Tags: reactjs, callback, fetch

I have two component parent and child.

I am passing callback function to child component like this.

```
<ChildComponent onFetchRecords={this.onFetchRecords} />
```

and inside child component I am calling this callback function like this.

```
this.props.onFetchRecords && this.props.onFetchRecords(0, 20).then(x => {
                // some code
            });
```

and on my parent component function body is like below:

```
    onFetchRecords(){
        return Client.sendJsonRequest("", "Records.json", "GET", "", "", this.handleResults, this.handleError, true, this.handleHttpError, "Reports");
      }

     handleResults(response){

     }
```

So as you can see **onFetchRecords** makes an `fetch` request to get specific file and then callback function **handleResults** gets called.

I want to pass the results to child components, is there any way to achieve the same?

I know, I can move whole `fetch` call to child itself but I don't want to do that because the callback function will keep on changing based on parent component and hence I want it to be configurable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of depending on the promise to pass you the updated result, you can pass the data to child using props

Render child like

```
<ChildComponent onFetchRecords={this.onFetchRecords}  records={this.state.records}/>
```

and in child call onFetchRecords

```
this.props.onFetchRecords && this.props.onFetchRecords(0, 20);
```

Now your fetch request in parent will be like

```
  onFetchRecords(){
    return Client.sendJsonRequest("", "Records.json", "GET", "", "", this.handleResults, this.handleError, true, this.handleHttpError, "Reports");
  }

 handleResults(response){
      this.setState({records: response});
 }
```

Now in child component if you want to take some action on prop change, you can implement `componentDidUpdate method`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   if(!_.isEqual(this.props.records, prevProps.records)) {
      // write your code here
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response but on child component I need to do further processing based on result. So I want child to listen for the success result and do the processing. So this way will not suit in my scenario.

Comment: Updating my answer for that